# converting Binary Numbers in to decimal numbers

Tags: java, c++

I need a program to convert Binary numbers into Decimal number in Java or in C++.

is there some one who can help me.

Comment: By "Binary Numbers", do you mean a string containing 0 and 1 characters?

Comment: imho if someone asks to give him a hand with a particular algorithm/technique/whatever, why should you think 'Oh, it's his homework, I'm not going to write my opinion'? Something changes if it's his homework?

Comment: If it's homework, he probably doesn't want the "strtol" answer.

Comment: @chester89: It's also bad form to give code answers to homework.  It's better practice to explain the concepts and give hints, so they still have to work it the details themselves.  It is supposed to be practice after all, not "got this from the internet"

Answer (score 12):

Java:

```
String binary = "110010101011";
int decimal = Integer.parseInt(binary, 2);
```

C++:

```
#include <cstdlib>
const char* binary = "110010101011";
int decimal = strtol(binary, NULL, 2);
```

Here's the [Javadoc page for Integer.parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) and here's the [manpage for strotol](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol).

Answer (score 1):

Use binary expansion.  For example 1101 1001 is:

(1 x 2^7) + (1 x 2^6) + (1 x 2^4) + (1 x 2^3) + (1 x 2^0)

which is equal to:

217 in decimal.

Here is the algorithm:

1.) Prompt the user for a binary number.

2.) Store the number in an array.  The first element i.e. anArray[0] should contain a value of 1, the second element should have a value of 0 . . .

3.) Implement a for loop to do the calculation.

Comment: Better written as
1 << 7 | 1 << 6 | 1 << 4 | 1 << 3 | 1 << 0

Answer (score 0):

In C++, there are the library functions "strtol", "strtoull", etc. that take a string and the base to use for conversion.  If you need more than 32 / 64 bits, then you can use the GMP library which is only limited by available memory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know how.

Use:

```
String input0 = "1010";
String input1 = "10";

int number0 = Integer.parseInt(input0, 2);
int number1 = Integer.parseInt(input1, 2);

int sum = number0 + number1;`
```

Answer (score 0):

Good C function [itoa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/)

Answer (score -1):

Algorithmically (in c/c++):

```
const char* binary = "110010101011";
int decimal = 0;

while ( *binary ) 
{
    decimal*=2;
    decimal+=*binary-'0';
    binary++ ;
 }
```

Note that this doesn't handle invalid characters (anything other than binary digits).

Comment: Interesting.  I posted a correct answer, the only one showing a working algorithm, and it gets downvoted 6 years later.  What's the deal?