# How to convert a Binary String to a base 10 integer in Java

Tags: java, string, binary, radix

I have an array of Strings that represent Binary numbers (without leading zeroes) that I want to convert to their corresponding base 10 numbers. Consider:

```
binary 1011 becomes integer 11
binary 1001 becomes integer 9
binary   11 becomes integer 3   etc.
```

What's the best way to proceed? I've been exploring java.lang.number.* without finding a direct conversion method. `Integer.parseInt(b)` yields an integer EQUAL to the String...e.g., 1001 becomes 1,001 instead of 9...and does not seem to include a parameter for an output base. `toBinaryString` does the conversion the wrong direction. I suspect I'll need to do a multistep conversion, but can't seem to find the right combination of methods or subclasses. I'm also not sure the extent to which leading zeros or lack thereof will be an issue. Anyone have any good directions to point me?

Comment: Look at [Integer#parseInt(String s, int radix)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Comment: possible duplicate of [converting Binary Numbers in to decimal numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115346/converting-binary-numbers-in-to-decimal-numbers)

Answer (score 374, accepted):

You need to [specify the radix](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29). There's an overload of `Integer#parseInt()` which allows you to.

```
int foo = Integer.parseInt("1001", 2);
```

Comment: Perfection. I completely missed the second line on the parseInt documentation that allows for the radix. Works like a dream.

Comment: Does this work with leading zeros too? Just confirming, although I see no reason why not.

Comment: @NagabhushanBaddi example? Are you passing a two's complement representation?

Answer (score 25):

This might work:

```
public int binaryToInteger(String binary) {
    char[] numbers = binary.toCharArray();
    int result = 0;
    for(int i=numbers.length - 1; i>=0; i--)
        if(numbers[i]=='1')
            result += Math.pow(2, (numbers.length-i - 1));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I suppose it is kind of unnecessary. That's what happens when you have a little time between classes.

Comment: this one is helpful for me because I have to do a school project with conversions without using the ones java already has

Comment: Did anyone test this before? here number.length minus the index plus 1 is been multiply by 2, if i am not mistaken in bynary you start with 1 and multiply that value by 2 then grab the result and multiply that one  by 2 that will be your 3 place and so on

Comment: (COMMENT BOX IS NOT GOOD FOR SNIPPETS) Here the Code that i am using base in yours (I was lost and use yours as a template)
  public static int binaryToInteger(String binary)
        {
            char[] numbers = binary.ToCharArray();
            int result = 0;
            int posValue = 1;
            for (int i = numbers.Length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
            {
                if (numbers[i] == '1')
                {
                    result += posValue;
                }
                posValue *= 2;
            }
            return result;
        }

Comment: This code snippet is not working. `for` loop and calculation of new `result` variable is not correct.

Comment: `i==0;` that won't work why so many upvotes for a not working code?

Comment: @fubo Well, I hadn't tested it. I updated it to work now, but anyway, this solution is far from perfect and you should probably use Matt's solution instead.

Comment: It's good for learning instead of having some high level function spur out some numbers.

Comment: This is really inefficient. Why the high number of upvotes I don't understand :(.

Answer (score 15):

```
int foo = Integer.parseInt("1001", 2);
```

works just fine if you are dealing with positive numbers but if you need to deal with signed numbers you may need to sign extend your string then convert to an Int

```
public class bit_fun {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x= (int)Long.parseLong("FFFFFFFF", 16);
        System.out.println("x =" +x);       

        System.out.println(signExtend("1"));
        x= (int)Long.parseLong(signExtend("1"), 2);
        System.out.println("x =" +x);

        System.out.println(signExtend("0"));
        x= (int)Long.parseLong(signExtend("0"), 2);
        System.out.println("x =" +x);

        System.out.println(signExtend("1000"));
        x= (int)Long.parseLong(signExtend("1000"), 2);
        System.out.println("x =" +x);

        System.out.println(signExtend("01000"));
        x= (int)Long.parseLong(signExtend("01000"), 2);
        System.out.println("x =" +x);
    }

    private static String signExtend(String str){
        //TODO add bounds checking
        int n=32-str.length();
        char[] sign_ext = new char[n];
        Arrays.fill(sign_ext, str.charAt(0));

        return new String(sign_ext)+str;
    }
}

output:
x =-1
11111111111111111111111111111111
x =-1
00000000000000000000000000000000
x =0
11111111111111111111111111111000
x =-8
00000000000000000000000000001000
x =8
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: I needed -1 converted from binary to decimal, i did this. 
System.out.println((int)Long.parseLong("11111111111111111111111111111111",2));

Answer (score 6):

```
static int binaryToInt (String binary){
    char []cA = binary.toCharArray();
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = cA.length-1;i>=0;i--){
        //111 , length = 3, i = 2, 2^(3-3) + 2^(3-2)
        //                    0           1  
        if(cA[i]=='1') result+=Math.pow(2, cA.length-i-1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using bitshift is more elegant and faster than `Math.pow`. Simply bitshift the digits (0 or 1) into position with `val <<= 1`

```java
// parse an unsigned binary string, valid up to 31 bits
static int binaryToBase10(String binaryString) {
    int val = 0;
    for (char c : binaryString.toCharArray()) {
        val <<= 1;
        val += c-'0';
    }
    return val;
}
```

**Example use**

```java
int val = binaryToBase10("1011");
System.out.println(val);
```

prints 11

Answer (score 3):

```
public Integer binaryToInteger(String binary){
    char[] numbers = binary.toCharArray();
    Integer result = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=numbers.length-1;i>=0;i--){
         if(numbers[i]=='1')result+=(int)Math.pow(2, count);
         count++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I guess I'm even more bored! Modified Hassan's answer to function correctly.

Answer (score 3):

For me I got NumberFormatException when trying to deal with the negative numbers. I used the following for the negative and positive numbers.

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseUnsignedInt("11111111111111111111111111110111", 2));      

Output : -9
```

Answer (score 0):

I love loops! Yay!

```
String myString = "1001001"; //73
```

While loop with accumulator, left to right (`l` doesn't change):

```
int n = 0,
    j = -1,
    l = myString.length();
while (++j < l) n = (n << 1) + (myString.charAt(j) == '0' ? 0 : 1);
return n;
```

Right to left with 2 loop vars, inspired by [Convert boolean to int in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3793650/2371861) (absolutely horrible):

```
int n = 0,
    j = myString.length,
    i = 1;
while (j-- != 0) n -= (i = i << 1) * new Boolean(myString.charAt(j) == '0').compareTo(true);
return n >> 1;
```

A somewhat more reasonable implementation:

```
int n = 0,
    j = myString.length(),
    i = 1;
while (j-- != 0) n += (i = i << 1) * (myString.charAt(j) == '0' ? 0 : 1);
return n >> 1;
```

A readable version :p

```
int n = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < myString.length(); j++) {
    n *= 2;
    n += myString.charAt(j) == '0' ? 0 : 1;
}
return n;
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed version of java's Integer.parseInt(text) to work with negative numbers:

```
public static int parseInt(String binary) {
    if (binary.length() < Integer.SIZE) return Integer.parseInt(binary, 2);

    int result = 0;
    byte[] bytes = binary.getBytes();

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        if (bytes[i] == 49) {
            result = result | (1 << (bytes.length - 1 - i));
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you want to do from binary string to Decimal but Afterword, You might be needed contrary method. It's down below.

```
public static String decimalToBinaryString(int value) {
    String str = "";
    while(value > 0) {
        if(value % 2 == 1) {
            str = "1"+str;
        } else {
            str = "0"+str;
        }
        value /= 2;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this method to convert the binary to decimal integer if you are given with string.(Java Language)

```
static int binaryTodecimal(String s){
    int i= -1;
    char[] str = s.toCharArray();
    int dec_val= 0;
    
    for (int j=str.length-1; j>=0 ;j-- ){
        int k= Integer.valueOf(str[j]) - '0';
        i = i+1;
        dec_val += k*(Math.pow(2, i));
        
    }
    System.out.println(dec_val);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're worried about performance, `Integer.parseInt()` and `Math.pow()` are too expensive. You can use bit manipulation to do the same thing twice as fast (based on my experience):

```
final int num = 87;
String biStr = Integer.toBinaryString(num);

System.out.println(" Input Number: " + num + " toBinary "+ biStr);
int dec = binaryStringToDecimal(biStr);
System.out.println("Output Number: " + dec + " toBinary "+Integer.toBinaryString(dec));
```

Where

```
int binaryStringToDecimal(String biString){
  int n = biString.length();      
  int decimal = 0;
  for (int d = 0; d < n; d++){
    // append a bit=0 (i.e. shift left) 
    decimal = decimal << 1;

    // if biStr[d] is 1, flip last added bit=0 to 1 
    if (biString.charAt(d) == '1'){
      decimal = decimal | 1; // e.g. dec = 110 | (00)1 = 111
    }
  }
  return decimal;
}
```

Output:

```
 Input Number: 87 toBinary 1010111
Output Number: 87 toBinary 1010111
```