# printing an array however getting uncessary numbers

Tags: java

I have a text file that has lines of 1's and 0's. However it's printing gibberish when I want the actual number, I think it is loaded in the array correctly but it's not printing.

```
10100010
10010010
10110101
11100011
10010100
01010100
10000100
11111111
00010100
```

Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Encoder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter file Name: ");

        Scanner getInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fileName = getInput.nextLine();

        File file = new File(fileName + ".txt");
        FileInputStream fstream = null;

        try {

            fstream = new FileInputStream(file);

            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine;

            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // print the content to console
                System.out.println(strLine);
                int[] n1 = new int[8];

                for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                    System.out.println((strLine.charAt(i)));
                    n1[i] = strLine.charAt(i + 1);

                }
                for (int n : n1) {
                    System.out.println(n + " ");
                }

                ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
            }

            in.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {// Catch exception if any
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        System.out.println("Even or Odd");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to transform a string of binary into an integer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178980/how-to-convert-a-binary-string-to-a-base-10-integer-in-java

Comment: no not trying to that, just print an array after the string has been loaded in to the array

Comment: Does it print an array that looks like this: [I@ae01b58 ?

Comment: What is the problem? "not printing" => what not print? where it stops?

Comment: I get : Please enter file Name: 
input
10100010
1
0
1
0
0
0
1
48 
49 
48 
48 
48 
49

Comment: don't kno where the 48's are coming from

Comment: `System.out.println(n + " ");` prints an int. int for char 0 is 48.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an `int` array. You are getting a `char` from the string. That `char` is an unsigned 16 bit int, and contains a numerical value used to map to a character set. For US_ASCII/UTF-8 this means `48` for the character '0' and `49` for the character '1'. When you assign that to an int in your array, that's what you get.

If you want the integer value represented by each character in the string (0 or 1), the easiest way would be to simply do:

```
n1[i] = Integer.valueOf(strLine.substring(i, i+1));
```

The `Integer` class provides a static method for converting a `String` representation of a integer to an `Integer` (which of course unboxes to an `int`). `String.substring()` returns a `String` rather than a `char`.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the integer value of the *characters* `0,1` which evaluate to 48 and 49 respectively.

```
n1[i] = strLine.charAt(i + 1);//casts the character to an int here
```

Create an array of characters, not ints.

I.e.

```
char[] n1 = char int[8];
```

instead of

```
int[] n1 = new int[8];
```