# NumberFormat error while trying to get binary values from string to integer variable

Tags: java, string, int

Hi I am new to Java and any help would be appreciated I am trying to convert an decimal number into binary and then making a left shift on that binary number. But it does not allow me left shift on string and it gives me exception of I try to convert it to integer.

```
                int i = 40700;
                iToBinary = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
                i = Integer.parseInt(iToBinary);
                i=i<<1;
```

What should be the optimal way to do this. I also need to convert the decimal to binary with the sign magnitude so I don't think a direct function like toBinaryString would work for me. But I would like to know how to do this.

Comment: While using shift operator there is always the risk of exceeding the integer limit. I think this has happened in your case. Please let me know if the answer I posted worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need additional parameter `radix` in `parseInt` method:
see this link for example: [How to convert a Binary String to a base 10 integer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178980/how-to-convert-a-binary-string-to-a-base-10-integer-in-java)

Here are java examples for this method:

```
Examples: 

     parseInt("0", 10) returns 0
     parseInt("473", 10) returns 473
     parseInt("+42", 10) returns 42
     parseInt("-0", 10) returns 0
     parseInt("-FF", 16) returns -255
     parseInt("1100110", 2) returns 102
```

In your case will be :

```
i = Integer.parseInt(iToBinary, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The binary string you are parsing is to large for an integer. Try the following:

```
long i = 40700;
iToBinary = Long.toBinaryString(i);
i = Long.parseLong(iToBinary);
i=i<<1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be of help. Try

```
     int i = 40700;
     String iToBinary = Integer.toBinaryString(i<<1);
     Long z = Long.parseLong(iToBinary,2);
     System.out.println(" i " + z);
```

The answer we get is 81400

Answer (score 0):

To solve your exception you can use the overloaded method of `Integer.parseInt` using two parameters, then you can define the `radix`.

Change this line:

```
i = Integer.parseInt(iToBinary);
```

To this:

```
i = Integer.parseInt(iToBinary, 2);
```