# How to convert a large string of integers to binary?

Tags: java, string, binary, data-conversion

[EDITED]

Apologies if this has been answered already in a different thread. I was asked this question in a recent interview. Given a large string of integers(> 64bit), say, "163878712638127812737637876347236482", how would you convert it to binary? This should be done without the use of binary related java API or libraries.

Comment: As a single large number or as individual digits?

Comment: Check out the BigInteger class.

Comment: If you want to convert each integer use Integer.toBinaryString. To convert all as a single string see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178980/how-to-convert-a-binary-string-to-a-base-10-integer-in-java.

Comment: If I asked this in an interview, I probably wouldn't want `BigInteger.toByteArray`; I'd want you to write the actual code that does this. Do you know in general how to convert numbers to a different base? If not, that'd where I'd start googling. And if you do know how to do that, then pick a way to represent the big integer (such as a `String`, or `byte[]`, or whatever) and just implement that base-converting algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

Create a [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) from the String and call [toByteArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toByteArray--).

Answer (score 0):

Brett's method should work. 
But in case that you are not allowed to use any external libraries, you can treat the string as an array of digits and perform long division on it. So you divide the number by 2 repeatedly until you get 0 or 1 left.
You might have to write your own method to do the division on an array of digits (deal with leftovers and remainders), but it should have a pretty good run time.

Here's an example:
Lets say you have the string 163878712638127812737637876347236482.
Convert it to an array of ints (or shorts if memory is a concern).
Perform a long division by 2, keep result in a separate array and keep track of the remainder:

```
int[] answer = new int[input.length]; //create the answer array
String binary = "";
public void convert(input, answer){
    for(int i=input.length-1;i<=0;i--) //you want to start from the left end
    {
        int temp = input[i]/2; //int division, disregard decimal.
        answer[i] = temp;
        int remainder = input[i] - temp*2; //will be 1 or 0, carry over to the next digit
        if(i>0) //check if we are not at the last digit
            input[i-1] += 10*remainder;
        else
            binary = remainder+binary; //add new bit to the left of the binary
    }
    if(answer_is_smaller_than_2) //check if we have 0 or 1 left, maybe just go through the answer array
       binary = answer[0]+binary;// add the last digit to binary string. It is generally ok to have a 0 in the beginning, but you can easily do a check and remove the 0
    else convert(answer, new int[answer.length]); //keep dividing

}
```

Sorry that the recursion is not very polished. I wrote it on a run. 
For more information on converting decimal to binary:
http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Decimal-to-Binary
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi Yang, you are right. I don't want to be using external libraries. If that's the case, could you please go over an example explaining your solution to me?

Comment: `BigInteger` is **not** an *external library*. `java.math.BigInteger` should make that obvious.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion. I really want to say any library i.e. no import statement :P The point here is that it's for an interview, so he probably wants to write his own function for conversion, not rely on any available methods like toByteArray.

Answer (score 0):

I got to thinking about this problem and here's finally my solution. I was able to validate the output for 10 digit long numeric strings, but not for the string used in the program. It'd be great if someone can verify and tell me if the solution is correct. Also, the solution is unoptimized, so please feel free to suggest changes:

```
public class BinaryString {
    String finArr = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String num = "37489237892374892734872398479827498238932787";
        BinaryString bs = new BinaryString();
        bs.getBinaryValue(num);
    }

    void getBinaryValue(String num) {

        String quo = getBin(num);

        if (!quo.equals("1")) {
            getBinaryValue(quo);
        } else {
            finArr = quo + finArr;
            System.out.println(" Final Binary Value=" + finArr);
            return;
        }
    }

    String getBin(String num) {

        int[] numArr = new int[num.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
            numArr[i] = Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i));
        }
        int p = 0;
        String quo = "";
        int rem = numArr[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < numArr.length; i++) {

            p = rem / 2;
            if (p != 0) {
                quo = quo + p;
            } else if (p == 0 && i > 0) {
                quo = quo + p;
            }

            if ((i + 1) != numArr.length) {
                rem = numArr[i] % 2 * 10 + numArr[i + 1];
            } else {
                rem = rem % 2;
                break;
            }

        }

        finArr = Integer.toString(rem) + finArr;
        return quo;

    }

}
```

Output:

Final Binary Value=1101011100101101011110111111010001110101100001011011011110010001000101111111100101111101100001010010001101100101101001110011101101111011100110011

Comment: Verified for the string in the program

 C:\Users\XXXX>python
Python 3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 0b1101011100101101011110111111010001110101100001011011011110010001000101111111100101111101100001010010001101100101101001110011101101111011100110011 == 37489237892374892734872398479827498238932787
True
>>>