# Binary to Int Using Recursion

Tags: java, recursion, binary

I have the following code for a recursive function to convert binary to int:

```
public static int binaryToInt( String b ) {

    if(b.length() < 2) {
        return 0;
    }

    return b.charAt(0) * (int) Math.pow(2, b.length()) + binaryToInt(b.substring(1));

}
```

I am not getting the correct values for example: "101" I get 584. 
I thought my logic is correct but can someone please point out where i am going wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a Binary String to a base 10 integer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178980/how-to-convert-a-binary-string-to-a-base-10-integer-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few problems

1. `b.charAt(0) * ...` - You are multiplying the ASCII value of the character and an int. Change it to `b.charAt(0) - '0'` to get the actual integer.
2. `Math.pow(2, b.length())` - It has to `Math.pow(2, b.length() - 1)`. Working for a few samples with a pen and paper will explain this.
3. The base condition is wrong. You need to return when there are no more characters left. So, it must be `if(b.length() == 0)`

Comment: @Henry Just added that :)

Answer (score 1):

**First:**
I changed your base criteria to allow all of the bits in calculation:

```
if(b.length() <= 0) {
    return 0;
 }
```

**Second:** `b.charAt(0)` return the ASCII value not the integer, so make it integer by using: `(b.charAt(0) - '0')`

**Third:** The power of each position will be `length-1`, so changed as following:

```
Math.pow(2, b.length()-1)
```

> **Final solution:**

Please check the final solution:

```
public static int binaryToInt( String b ) {

    if(b.length() <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    return (b.charAt(0) - '0') * (int) Math.pow(2, b.length()-1) + binaryToInt(b.substring(1));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have has the following errors:

1. b.charAt(0)- returns the ASCII value of the character that means result is 
   calculated as ASCCI value (i.e if b.charAt(0) returns 1 then its corresponding 
   ASCII value is 49).
2. if (b.length() < 2)- You are not checking the value of string what if the value is 1 still it returns 0.
3. the Math.pow(2, b.length()) to be modified as Math.pow(2, b.length()-1)

Here is the code:

```
public static int binaryToInt( String b ) {

    if(b.length() < 2) {
        if(b.charAt(0)=='1')
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }

    return Character.getNumericValue(b.charAt(0)) * (int) Math.pow(2, b.length()-1) + binaryToInt(b.substring(1));

}
```

Comment: Please let me know you are satisfied with the answer or not:)