# How to perform boolean operations in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, boolean-operations

I want to add two bolean vectors

```
vector<bool> v1= {0,0,1}
vector<bool> v2= {1,0,1}
vector<bool> resultedVector = v1+v2
```

The answer should be:

```
resultedVector = {1,1,0};
```

Does anyone know, how to do in `c++/c++11` ?
I want to increment every time given boolean vector by 1. And just want to use binary operations. Or could create bolean truth table of given number of variable.

Comment: You want to append vectors?

Comment: Have you looked at std::bitset : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset ?

Comment: I just added question, I want perform addition. resulted vector would be same size.

Comment: In my code, the size of bits are not fixed, in next loop, it could be changed. So bitset does not work.

Comment: Why are you initializing your vectors of `bool` with`int`egers rather than `bool`eans? Just currious :)

Comment: @Luqman Sounds like you should just be using `int`s for the math, and then pull out the bits you care about at the end.

Comment: Addition isn't really a boolean operation. You seem to be looking for something like an arbitrary precision int?

Comment: What you have provided has nothing to do with boolean operations. Rather, you want to implement binary addition.

Comment: @AndyG , yes you are right. I want to perform binary operation.

Comment: @Luqman Can't you just add your values together in decimal and then grab the binary representation if you need that for some reason?

Comment: @Luqman  It is not clear how the result vector is gotten. What operations are used?

Comment: @aardvarkk thats question, how to get binary representation, I made code which manually calculates binary, but I could not find built in function like following:
bool vector = bool(decimal);

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` is pretty ugly beast and I think you chosen wrong data type. Much more efficient would be to use `std::vector<uint32_t>` or similar and implement access of bits and binary addition over that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform binary addition in C++, you can use the function described here:
[Adding binary numbers in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282825/adding-binary-numbers-in-c)

I implemented the function from that link to fit your specifications like this:

```
std::vector<bool> add(const std::vector<bool>& a, const std::vector<bool>& b)
{
        bool c;
        std::vector<bool> result;
        for(int i = 0; i < a.size() ; i++){
                result.push_back(false);
                result[i] = ((a[i] ^ b[i]) ^ c); // c is carry
                c = ((a[i] & b[i]) | (a[i] & c)) | (b[i] & c);
        }
        return result;
}
```

This function takes two vectors of bools (and assumes they are the same size) and returns their result vector. Obviously this function doesn't handle overflow or numbers of different sizes. You can modify it yourself if you need those capabilities. Also, you seem to be talking about an overloaded operator for a bool vector, and you can do that by checking out operator overloading, but this logic will allow you to add two boolean numbers stored in vectors.

Comment: That method would be extremely slow, comparing to embedded addition.

Comment: Yeah, obviously the best way to do this is to use an existing type like an int and perform the boolean operations through integer addition, but I answered this question assuming we needed to use a vector.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can use a stateful functor:

```
struct BitAdder {
    bool carry_ = 0x0;  // Range is [0, 1].

    // Only accepts single bit values for a and b.
    bool operator()(bool a, bool b) {
        assert(a == (a & 0x1) && b == (b & 0x1));
        char sum = a + b + carry_;
        carry_ = (sum & 0x2) >> 1;  // Keep in range.
        return sum & 0x1;
    }
};

// Code is more straightforward when bits are stored in reverse.
std::vector<bool> v = {0, 1, 1, 1, 0};  // To be interpreted as:  1110 (14).
std::vector<bool> w = {1, 0, 1, 1, 0};  // To be interpreted as:  1101 (13).
std::vector<bool> result = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};  //     Will become: 11011 (27).

assert(v.size() <= w.size());  // v and w can be iterated over together.
assert(v.size() <= result.size());  // There is enough space to store the bits.
assert(v[v.size() - 1] + w[v.size() - 1] < 2);  // No overflow can happen.
std::transform(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), w.cbegin(), result.begin(), BitAdder());

std::cout << "want: 11011, got: ";
std::copy(result.crbegin(), result.crend(), std::ostream_iterator<bool>(std::cout));
std::cout << '\n';
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bdcd71cead4e47c6)

Comment: What if the operands are of different sizes? `a + b + carry_` is not boolean arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand your question. Since this looks like homework and the point of the question seems to be operators overloading, here's an idea, not the complete answer:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector< bool > operator+( const std::vector<bool>& a, const std::vector<bool>& b )
{
  std::vector< bool > r;
  // your code goes here
  return r;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector< bool > a, b, c;
  c = a + b;
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT - one day later**

Here's a solution to your increment problem ([demo](http://ideone.com/jGzQFS)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// preinc - no grow on overflow
std::vector< bool >& operator++( std::vector<bool>& v )
{
  for ( auto e : v )
    if ( e = !e )
      break;
  return v;
}

// postinc - no grow on overflow
std::vector< bool > operator++( std::vector<bool>& v, int )
{
  auto t { v };
  operator++( v );
  return t;
}

// insert
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, const std::vector< bool > v )
{
  for ( std::vector< bool >::const_reverse_iterator ci = v.rbegin(); ci != v.rend(); ++ci )
    os << *ci ? '1' : '0';
  return os;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector< bool > b {0,0,0,0};
  for ( int i = 0; i < 16; ++i )
  {
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    ++b;
  }

  return 0;
}
```