# Outputting the result of an addition of two binary strings with their decimal value in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, gcc, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to go through some bit manipulation problems. This is a little bit tedious because I'm just starting to learn how to make functions that does bit manipulations for practice (technical interviews, general concepts, functionalities, different approaches, etc...)

My goal with my problem is able to add two binary strings as my parameters from my compiled program (`./a.out binary1 + binary2`). We are limited that the length will be always size of 6 characters (000000 for the min and 111111 for the max binary values, plus it will be never be above of 111111). The result of the addition of both binary strings will give us another binary string number AND the decimal represent. For a quick example, if we run `./a.out 000010 + 000001` our output should gives us `000011 (3)`.

This is my `decrypt.c` file:

```
int     toInt(char *bits)
{
    int decimal = 0;
    int base = 1;
    int len = strlen(bits);

    for (int i = len-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (bits[i] == '1')
            decimal += base;
        base *= 2;
    }
    return (decimal);
}

int makeEqualLength(char *str1, char *str2)
{
    int len1 = strlen(str1);
    int len2 = strlen(str2);
    if (len1 < len2)
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < len2 - len1 ; i++)
            str1 += '0';
        return len2;
    }
    else if (len1 > len2)
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < len1 - len2 ; i++)
            str2 += '0';
    }
    return len1; // If len1 >= len2
}

char    *getSum(char *a, char *b)
{
    int len = makeEqualLength(a, b);
    char *res = calloc(6, sizeof(char*));
    int num_a;
    int num_b;
    int c = 0;
    int total = 0;

    for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        num_a = toInt(a) - '0';
        num_b = toInt(b) - '0';
        total = (num_a ^ num_b ^ c) + '0';
        res[i] += (char)total;
        c = (num_a & num_b) | (num_b & c) | (num_a & c);
    }
    if (c)
        res += (char)'1';
    return (res);
}
```

To explain what I was trying to do is a **half-adder** method where you have the carrier of the addition and a result. I first need to determine the size of both binary strings by making a function called `makeEqualLength`. This will get the size of both strings and use it later on the half-adder. To make binary to decimal, I check if there is a character representing `1` in any base. If there is a `1`, then add it up to the decimal. My result with hold the result of the addition of the two binary strings.

And this is the given file `main.c` file to run with:

```
#include <stdio.h> //printf, scanf, ...
#include <string.h> //memcpy, strlen, ...
#include <unistd.h> //fork, write, sleep...
#include <stdlib.h> //malloc, free, exit...

#include "header.h"

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    char *a;
    char *b;

    if (ac == 4 && strcmp(av[2], "+") == 0
        && strlen(av[1]) == 6 && strlen(av[3]) == 6
        && checkBinary(av[1]) && checkBinary(av[3])) {
        a = av[1];
        b = av[3];
    }else{
        printf("Usage: ./sum 000010 + 000001\n");
        return (0);
    }

    char *sum;

    sum = getSum(a, b);
    printf("%s (%d)\n", sum, toInt(sum));

    return (0);
}


int checkBinary(char *str) {
    int i = 0;

    while (str[i]) {
        if (str[i] != '0' && str[i] != '1')
            return (0);
        i++;
    }
    return (1);
}
```

My answer is not returning correctly, which is giving me `(0)` and nothing else. Does anybody have an idea how can I resolve this problem?

Have a nice day/night :)!

Comment: `str1 += '0'` does not append a character to a string of type `char*` (just in case you expect this statement to do so)

Comment: Why 6 in `char *res = calloc(6, sizeof(char*));`?  I'd expect `calloc(len + 1 + 1, sizeof *res)`

Comment: Your function `makeEqualLength()` only "works" because in `main()` it is already established that both strings are of the same length which is 6. So your `makeEqualLength()` will always only return `len1` (`strlen(str1)`) and do nothing else ever. Throw it away.

Comment: You are right @Swordfish. I will take it out.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, it is close to what I thought so I had to fix few things over to make it more readable. Interesting observation with my appending part and I noticed that I don't need to cast anything extra for no reason. This is what I ended up getting for my **working solution**:

```
char    *getSum(char *a, char *b)
{
    char *res = calloc(7, sizeof(*res));
    int num_a;
    int num_b;
    int c = 0;

    for (int i = 5; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        num_a = (a[i] == '1') ? 1 : 0;
        num_b = (b[i] == '1') ? 1 : 0;
        c += num_a + num_b;
        res[i] += (c % 2) + '0';
        c /= 2;
    }
    return (res);
}
```

Now in this one, I tried to do some usage for half-adder with bit-manipulation, but it is not outputting correctly my numbers:

```
char    *getSum(char *a, char *b)
{
    char *res = calloc(7, sizeof(*res));
    int num_a;
    int num_b;
    int c = 0;

    res[6] = '\0';
    for (int i = 5; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        num_a = (a[i] == '1') ? 1 : 0;
        num_b = (b[i] == '1') ? 1 : 0;
        c = (((num_a ^ num_b)) ^ c) + '0';
        res[i] += (c % 2) + '0';
        c = ((num_a & num_b) | (num_b & c)) | (num_a & c);
    }
    return (res);
}
```

I prefer the last example, but when it comes to adding the numbers/binaries together, it will output incorrectly (000010 + 000001 gives me -> 000001 as a binary and 1 in decimal. Any ideas where my logic is failing? I followed up with this idea from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13283126/6017248)